# Python bisect_left and bisect_right to identify if item is in list and start and end of item

Tags: python

I have large sorted lists (> 10k elements) with duplicate values where I need to know if an item is in the list, and if it's there, the start and end position of the item. I have thought of this function to do both at the same time:

```
def FctMultipleBinarySearch(s, sList):

    indexL = bisect.bisect_left(sList, s)
    indexR = bisect.bisect_right(sList, s)
    
    # nItem = 0 if item is not in list 
    nItem = indexR - indexL
   
    return indexL, nItem
```

Using that function, the first check would be to look the value of nItem, if it's greater than 0, then this means the item is in the list.

I have tested with different cases, both numeral and alpha like so:

```
sList = [0, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 8, 8, 9, 10]
s = [-1, 0, 4, 5.5, 8, 10, 11]
```

which gives me that -1, 5.5 and 11 are not part of the list, and the proper info for the rest of the value

```
sList = ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Chocolate', 'Chocolate']
s = ['Anana', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Chocolat', 'Chocolate', 'Pineapple']
```

which give me that Anana, Chocolat and Pineapple are not part of the list, and the proper info for the rest of the value.

Is this a good or bad idea, in terms of speed, reliability, etc.?

Comment: This approach is correct, your code works. Please either explain the issue you're having trouble with or consider asking on codereview SE instead.

Comment: The only down-side to this technique is that you have to execute both bisect_left **and** bisect_right in order to determine an item's existence. If there was a C-based binary search available (maybe there is?), then you'd know immediately if the  item exists in the list. However, if it did exist (and you know its index) you then have to search left/right to determine the bounds - which then leads to further [potential] inefficiencies

Comment: @Codist Why do you have to execute both? You can just execute one and look there. What difference does a C-based one make? CPython's *is* in C, btw.

Comment: To avoid `bisect_right` if nothing is found, you can just perform one comparison with element at the returned index. If equal, search for the right position, otherwise element is not found - return zero. @KellyBundy I suspect direct access to C implementation would allow to continue without this comparison, since it was already performed under the hood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, that would depend on the average repetition of items (lets call it R).  Searching sequentially for the next non-equal value starting from the position of bisect_left will add R iterations.  Using bisect_right will cost log(N) iterations (where N is the size of the list), so, if R is less than log(N), sequential search from a starting point would be more efficient.

In practice, using bisect_right will probably be faster because all its iterations are performed in low level C code and the sequential approach would require much slower Python code.

There is no difference in terms of reliability but the binary+sequential approach would require you to write more code which, simple as it may be, is a potential source of mistakes and a maintenance burden.

If you are going to call this function a lot on the same list (and don't need positions for missing items), you may want to create an indexing dictionary and use it instead:

```
sList = ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Chocolate', 'Chocolate']

from itertools import groupby
sDict = {k:(idx[0],len(idx)) for k,(*idx,) 
         in groupby(range(len(sList)),lambda i:sList[i])}

print(sDict)
{'Apple': (0, 3), 'Banana': (3, 1), 'Chocolate': (4, 2)}

s = ['Anana', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Chocolat', 'Chocolate', 'Pineapple']
for k in s:
    print(k,sDict.get(k))

Anana None
Apple (0, 3)
Banana (3, 1)
Chocolat None
Chocolate (4, 2)
Pineapple None
```